# Why can I see stored procs and scalar functions in Entity Framework data model but not my controller?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I created a new project in my MVC 3 solution with a database-first Entity Framework model mapped to a SQL Server 2008 database. I included all tables, views, stored procs, etc in the model. I can see the scalar function I want to use when viewing the data model, but when I try to use a proc or function name as an object in my controller, Intellisense doesn't see it and the application errors out. Is there something else I need to be doing to use stored procedures and functions in my controller?

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.Entity;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;
 using JobBoard.Models;
 using JobBoardDAL.Models;

 namespace JobBoard.Controllers
 {
     public class AccountController : Controller       
     {


    private DataModel db = new DataModel();

    public ActionResult Authenticate() {
        .....
        var x = db.IsUser(somevariable); // <---- Problem is here
    {

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the SP's and functions to the edmx model, and map them to a complex type.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456824%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It didn't work for me. First I tried creating a function import using the scalar function. When that did not work I did some further research and it appears that EF does not have direct support for scalar functions, so I created a stored procedure with my function code instead and then regenerated the model. My stored procedure now shows as a function import but I still cannot call it from my controller. I additionally created another function import with a different name using the same stored proc. Same result. Am I missing a step?